# Linker error: Multiple definitions of 'ff_log2_tab'

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I am trying to build a shared library that links a static version of libav into it. I build the library with `--enable-pic` to make sure its usable for me. But upon linking with the following command:

```
g++ -shared -o libbrake.so -L./ -L./libs -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,-Bsymbolic  -lavcodec -lavfilter -lavformat -lavresample -lavutil -lswscale -lbluray -ldvdnav -ldvdread -lhandbrake -lvpx -ldl -lm -lpthread -lx264 -ltheoraenc -lvorbis -ljansson -la52 -lass -lbz2 -lz -lxml2 -lopus -lmp3lame -logg -lsamplerate -lfontconfig -ldca -lharfbuzz
```

The needed static libs of libav are in the `./libs` directory as `.a` archives.

Upon linking I get the error:

```
./libs/libavformat.a(log2_tab.o):(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `ff_log2_tab'
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Find where the second definition is (`nm` is your friend).

Comment: Ive done it now this way: with `ar d` i delete the multiple object file. but i think this is pretty "dirty"

Answer (score -2):

Ive done it now this way: with `ar d` i delete the multiple object file. but i think this is pretty "dirty"
                    – Nidhoegger